# How to set href value from page URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, src

If the URL is `www.mysite.com/?url=www.google.com?client=xxxxxx`

and the `a` href on the page is

```
<a href="" id="download" class="button">link</a>
```

how could I set the href as `http://www.google.com` by extracting it from `?url=www.google.com` to make...

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="download" class="button">link</a>
```

?

**And** there is one other factor: if the `?url=www.google.com` hasn't got `http://` after `?url=` then it should be inserted in the `href` value.

Comment: Is that URL right? Should it be `www.mysite.com/?url=www.google.com&client=xxxxxx`?

Comment: I think the 2nd question mark is supposed to be encoded: `www.mysite.com/?url=www.google.com%3Fclient=xxxxxx`

Comment: yes it is i just realised sorry

Comment: -1. Have you tried anything? This is super basic string manipulation and dom modification...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's hard to provide a definitive answer as I'm not sure what characters could appear in the the URL you need to parse but this will work with the URL you posted -

```
var url = "www.mysite.com/?url=www.google.com?client=xxxxxx"
url = url.split('?url=')[1].split(/\?|\%3F/)[0];
if (url.indexOf('http://') == -1)  url = 'http://' + url;
$("a#download").attr("href",url);
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/J77J2/

Comment: i have 1 problem with this var url = " i want it to get the url ive tried window.location.href but wont work